# why is the compliment of x or x -1?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I am stuck on this basic question:

```
int x=1;
printf(~x|x) // -1
```

Shouldn't it be ~`01|01   ~01 = 10   10|01 = 11 =3`   ?

Ok, after reading all the response, my understanding is that `1111=-1` on a twos compliment machine.

My follow up question is why is `1111 =-1` and not 15?

Thanks

Comment: the `~` happens first -- `(~x)|x`.  4-bit ex: `~0001 | 0001` --> `1110 | 0001` --> `1111` which is -1 (on a 2's complement machine).

Comment: Er...It's not good to change your question by editing it...

Comment: All bits set (however many that is for the type) is -1 on a 2's complement machine, for a signed integer type... in my comment that was 1111 because I was using 4-bits for an easy example -- actual types will have more bits.

Comment: If you write `unsigned int = 1; printf("%u", ~x|x);`, you will get a very large number(15, maybe). The most significant bit in a `signed int` is usually used to present its sign.

Comment: that gave me 4294967295

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, operator `~`(bitwise NOT) has a higher precedence than `|`(Bitwise OR).

When `sizeof (int) == 4`:

```
 x   = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001

~x   = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110

~x|x = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

For two's complement, `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` is just `-1`.

To answer your follow up question, you can run this code and see the result:

```
unsigned int x = 1;
printf("%u", ~x|x);
```

Comment: I am getting 4294967295

Comment: @Telenoobies So on your machine, `sizeof (int) == 4`. `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` is the binary representation of unsigned `4294967295`.

Comment: @Telenoobies However, whether `sizeof (int) == 4` doesn't actually matter. All `1` in the binary representation of an unsigned variable stands for the maximum it can reach, namely `UINT_MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's just assume 8-bit integers:

```
x    : 0000 0001
~x   : 1111 1110

~x|x : 1111 1111 == -1
```

In fact, this is always going to be the case, regardless of the value of `x`.  This operation sets all bits to 1.  Since your datatype is signed, and in this case negative values use twos-complement, the value will be -1.

Answer (score 0):

So why don't you just run it in computer? Actually`~` is prior to `|`,so we get

`~x=11111110(supposed  8-bit)`

then we use `|`,just change the first bit.So the answer is -1 which gets all bit equals to 1.